# SQL JOIN Column not found

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am really having mind blanks over what I have done wrong here.

I have 3 tables:

**cat_list (id,cat_title)**

**doc_list (id, doc_title)**

**cat_doc_link_table (id, link_doc_id, link_cat_id)**

I am trying to get any documents stored in the DB that associated with that category to show but I keep getting an error back:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'doc_list.link_doc_id' in 'on clause'
```

Here is my code for the cat_view page which is where it should list out the documents

```
<?php require_once '../db_con.php'; 

if(!empty($_GET['cat_id'])){
    $cat = intval($_GET['cat_id']);
try{
        $results = $dbh->query("SELECT *
                                FROM cat_List
                                INNER JOIN cat_doc_link_table
                                ON doc_list.link_doc_id = cat_doc_link_table.link_doc_id
                                WHERE cat_doc_link_table.link_cat_id = 3");

    } catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
    }

    $doc = $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    if($doc == FALSE){
        die();
    }
}

?>

   <p><?php 
   foreach($doc as $doc){
    echo '<span class="fullname"><a href="docView.php?doc_id='.$doc["doc_id"].'">'.$doc["doc_title"]. '</a></span><br>';
};?></p>
```

Comment: The statement is quite clear. `doc_list.link_doc_id` needs to be `doc_list.id`

Comment: That still fails though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this query instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM doc_list
INNER JOIN cat_doc_link_table
ON doc_list.id = cat_doc_link_table.link_doc_id
WHERE cat_doc_link_table.link_cat_id = 3
```

You were selecting from the `cat_list` table in the OP, which is not what you want since are looking for documents rather than categories.  You only need the `doc_list` and `cat_doc_link_table` tables.

You can use the `cat_id` directly in your query like this:

```
"SELECT * ... WHERE cat_doc_link_table.link_cat_id = {$cat};"
```

Comment: This worked but in reverse, it shows my categories and not the documents in the categories?

Comment: Ok, I see the error of my ways here, now the issue I have is that now I have explicitly set the ID to be 3, how do I grab the category number i am actually viewing?

Answer (score 1):

This is your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM cat_List INNER JOIN
     cat_doc_link_table
     ON doc_list.link_doc_id = cat_doc_link_table.link_doc_id
--------^
WHERE cat_doc_link_table.link_cat_id = 3;
```

The problem is shown.  There is no table alias called ``doc_list`in the`from` clause.  Hence the error.

It is good practice to qualify column names with their tables (as you do).  However, the code quickly becomes unreadable for mere mortals unless you use abbreviations for the table names.  So, I would recommend:

```
SELECT *
FROM cat_List l INNER JOIN
     cat_doc_link_table dlt
     ON l.id = dlt.link_cat_id
WHERE dlt.link_cat_id = 3;
```

I am guessing at what the id column is called in `cat_list`.

Also, you should not use `select *` when returning columns to an application.  Instead, list the columns that you are going to use.  That way, if the database structure changes, you will get an understandable query error rather than some strange application error.

Comment: That is good to know actually in regards to qualifying table names. I am really still struggling to get the docs to show when in the category view